# How to change profile in application.properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot to build an app, but don't know ow to change profile in application.properties file.
For example, I want to have 2 profiles: "dev" and "server" in my application. How could I do that?

Comment: You should check out the Spring docs, they have a section about profiles and application.properties - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles

Answer (score 6):

The following example shows how to change profile in an application.properties file:

```
spring.profiles.active= server
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `spring.profiles.active` property in `application.property` file which will be the default to be used. Create `application-dev.properties` and `application-server.properties` for your specific properties.

Application will start with profile as specified in `spring.active.profile` property. You can override this by providing command line argument `-Dspring.profiles.active`.

Answer (score 2):

you can set  spring.profiles.active=server  in application.properties